# Fixing an example of rewriting services between "value" and "factory"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I just made an attempt to simplify the example [(link)](http://plnkr.co/edit/7AKiKg14P1wrGonEniIY?p=preview) demonstrating the use of factory as services in angularJS.

Later I found the `value` and `constant` can further simplify the code. I had a replacement of the app.js with my code pasted below. For some reason it does not work with the same function.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.value(UserInformation, "angular");
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, UserInformation) {
   $scope.user = UserInformation;
});
app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, UserInformation) {
   $scope.user = UserInformation;
});
```

Can someone provide any guidance on how I should change the above code in order to give the same function as the original link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to app.value should be a string. Right now you're assigning it an undefined variable. Make the change below and it should work.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.value('UserInformation', {
  name: "Angular.js"
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, UserInformation) {
  $scope.user = UserInformation;
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, UserInformation) {
  $scope.user = UserInformation;
});
```

Comment: for OP case you get error: _TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of angular_

Comment: That is a good advice. But I changed it and it did not give the same function, unfortunately.

Comment: @JiajuShen this because in first function you return object with field `user` and in second - you return just `string`

Comment: @Grundy How can I change?

Comment: @JiajuShen I missed the link to the plunker... What Grundy said above sounds right about returning an object versus a string.

Comment: @JiajuShen check out my edit above. I changed the string to an object.

Comment: @rtucker88 Thank you!

Comment: @rtucker88 Do all services (value, constant, service, factor, etc) in AngularJS return objects?

Comment: @JiajuShen nope, they return that you return :-)

Comment: @rtucker88 Thank you. I would also like to know the reason why in this case particular we need to return an object for `app.value('UserInformation' ...)`? I've seen other `value` in angular that returns numbers and strings.

Comment: @JiajuShen the reason we need an object in this case is that your model is bound to user.name. We are binding UserInformation as user in your controller. If instead of user.name being the model it was just user, we could bind the name string directly.